# Iterate through rows in DataFrame and transform one to many

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

As an example in scala, I have a list and every item which matches a condition I want to appear twice (may not be the best option for this use case - but idea which counts):

```
l.flatMap {
  case n if n % 2 == 0 => List(n, n)
  case n => List(n)
}
```

I would like to do something similar in Spark - iterate over rows in a DataFrame and if a row matches a certain condition then I need to duplicate the row with some modifications in the copy. How can this be done?

For example, if my input is the table below:

```
| name  | age |
|-------|-----|
| Peter | 50  |
| Paul  | 60  |
| Mary  | 70  |
```

I want to iterate through the table and test each row against multiple conditions, and for each condition that matches, an entry should be created with the name of the matched condition.

E.g. condition #1 is "age > 60" and condition #2 is "name.length <=4". This should result in the following output:

```
| name  | age |condition|
|-------|-----|---------|
| Paul  | 60  |    2    |
| Mary  | 70  |    1    |
| Mary  | 70  |    2    |
```

Comment: You should be able to do it with `flatMap` as well. Can you show some actual data?

Comment: added example to make it clearer

Comment: Do you want to drop rows where `name.length > 4`, what if `age > 60` but also `name.length > 4`? Also do you need the *condition* column as well?

Comment: There should be an entry in the resulting table for each condition which the row matches. If there are no matches, then no entry, multiple matches means multiple entries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `filter` matching-conditions `dataframes` and then finally `union` all of them.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val condition1DF = df.filter($"age" > 60).withColumn("condition", lit(1))
val condition2DF = df.filter(length($"name") <= 4).withColumn("condition", lit(2))

val finalDF = condition1DF.union(condition2DF)
```

you should have your desired output as

```
+----+---+---------+
|name|age|condition|
+----+---+---------+
|Mary|70 |1        |
|Paul|60 |2        |
|Mary|70 |2        |
+----+---+---------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks, this solution gave me the most flexibility and was perfect for multiple conditions, conditions read from config, multiple tables etc

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a combination of an UDF and `explode()`, like in the following example:

```
// set up example data
case class Pers1 (name:String,age:Int)
val d = Seq(Pers1("Peter",50), Pers1("Paul",60), Pers1("Mary",70))
val df = spark.createDataFrame(d)

// conditions logic - complex as you'd like
// probably should use a Set instead of Sequence but I digress..
val conditions:(String,Int)=>Seq[Int] =  { (name,age) => 
    (if(age > 60) Seq(1) else Seq.empty) ++ 
    (if(name.length <=4) Seq(2) else Seq.empty)  
}
// define UDF for spark
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val conditionsUdf = udf(conditions)
// explode() works just like flatmap
val result  = df.withColumn("condition", 
   explode(conditionsUdf(col("name"), col("age"))))
result.show

+----+---+---------+
|name|age|condition|
+----+---+---------+
|Paul| 60|        2|
|Mary| 70|        1|
|Mary| 70|        2|
+----+---+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to flatten it with `rdd.flatMap`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val new_rdd = (df.rdd.flatMap(r => {
    val conditions = Seq((1, r.getAs[Int](1) > 60), (2, r.getAs[String](0).length <= 4))
    conditions.collect{ case (i, c) if c => Row.fromSeq(r.toSeq :+ i) }
}))

val new_schema = StructType(df.schema :+ StructField("condition", IntegerType, true))

spark.createDataFrame(new_rdd, new_schema).show
+----+---+---------+
|name|age|condition|
+----+---+---------+
|Paul| 60|        2|
|Mary| 70|        1|
|Mary| 70|        2|
+----+---+---------+
```

Comment: Why did you `df.rdd` to use `flatMap`?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I get errors if I don't use `rdd`. *Unable to find encoders...*.

Comment: @Psidom Try `import spark.implicits._`, with it you should be able to use `flatMap` on the dataframe instead. `spark` here is the `SparkSession`.